# Check if data is retrieved - CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I am retrieving data from CRM. I want to retrieve few fields from `quotedetail` . One of them is a  `int` field  `ad_discountpercent`.

This field doesn't necessary have a value.

I need to check if there is some value retrieved from that field and give it a default value `0` if there is no value.

Here is my code:

```
        string fetch1 = @"
                  <fetch count='50' >
                      <entity name='quotedetail' >
                        <attribute name='manualdiscountamount' />
                        <attribute name='priceperunit' />
                        <attribute name='ad_discountpercent' />
                        <attribute name='quantity' />
                        <attribute name='extendedamount' />
                      </entity>
                    </fetch>";

        EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch1));

        foreach (var c in result.Entities)
        {
             if(...)
        }
```

What should I put instead of `(...)` to see is there any data retrieved and give a default value? It would be helpful if you know and of these two things.

Lett me know if you need some additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access field value you can use `GetAttributeValue<T>(string attribute logical name)`

In your case:

```
c.GetAttributeValue<Entity>("ad_discountpercent");
```

Comment: What is the result type?

Comment: It depends on what you have in <> brackets . I guess you want  `c.GetAttributeValue<int>("ad_discountpercent")`  :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you want to update the `Entity` object (i.e., to save it back to CRM) or just need the value for processing.

```
if (!c.Attributes.Contains("ad_discountpercent"))
{
    var newEntity = new Entity(c.LogicalName, c.Id)
    newEntity["ad_discountpercent"] = 0; //replace 0 with your default value.   
}
```

Comment: Updated the code to better match your requirement. If you want to use `ExecuteMultiple` for performance on the update see my answer on another question for a basic implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500614/crm-dynamics-2013-sdk-update-current-accounts-with-2-values/36506904#36506904